# Selecting sample saze for imbalanced data for a Random Forest in r

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, sample-size

I have a large dataset (about 10000 rows) and I'm trying to run a classification random forest which I intend to use to make predictions. My data is every imbalanced. For the outcome variable I'm trying to predict about 89% of the rows is marked "1" and the remainder is "0".
The code I am using is as follows:

```
RFTry <-randomForest(as.factor(OutcomeVariable)~., data=df, importance=TRUE, 
ntree=200, samplesize=c(500,500))
```

I am unsure of what samplesize I should be using. Should I be sampling the same number of rows for each outcome variable or different? And how many samples should I be taking? Below shows a table of the number of variables in each.

```
> table(df$OutcomeVariable)

    0     1 
10228  1234
```

Thank you!

Comment: I used to run `randomForest` on 30K rows and I have no recollection of ever using `samplesize` and it worked well with the default settings.  My advice would be to start using mostly defaults and then change things only if necessary.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll give that a try! I've just seen so many warnings about using random forests on imbalanced data so thought I would get another opinion. Thank you for your response.

Comment: A question about oversampling small groups in imbalanced data for random forest would be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is about statistics in general and not really about `R`.

Comment: The imbalance does matter to some extent. The real concern is that in creating your training set, you might not get enough of the minority to build a solid predictor. If I were doing this, I would likely build 2 training sets and 2 test sets, each from a subset based on outcome (zero and one), then bring them back into one train and one test. This will guaranty that you have the same percentage of each in each set. You have a lot of data, so that should offset the relative disparity in classes if the predictors are appropriate and solidly tied to your outcomes.